# Post and/or Share Text/Images on Facebook Wall Server-Side With .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, sdk, server-side

I've spent a few days implementing Facebook's iOS SDK to allow our users to be able to login and then post text/images to their Facebook wall via our iOS application.  I've got that all working smoothly.

However, management would like to take an alternate direction for several reasons (which are irrelevant to me), whereas instead of posting on the device side (iOS), they would like the device side to use the iOS SDK in order to get the user to login and then capture the AccessToken.  Then, when the user chooses to share content from our app for example, they want to pass the AccessToken up to the server, and then have the .net/c# code do the actual posting of the text/image there.

1) Is this possible?

2) I see no official support from Facebook for a server-side api.  All I see is that they support Mobile and Web (client-side).

3) Through my SO and other online searches, I've seen some very out-dated attempts at an open-source .net Facebook SDK, but they seem to have been abandoned.

4) I do know that it's possible server-side (using the oAuth api) to login and gather some user information, like name/profile photo).  But that is not what I need.  I need the opposite.  I need to login on the client-side, but post/share on the server-side.

Any help and/or direction on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _“I see no official support from Facebook for a server-side api”_ – that’s because there is no such thing as a “client-side API” either. There is **one** API, and communication with it is done via HTTPS. So even without an SDK for your specific language/platform, basically all you need is the ability to make HTTPS requests.

Comment: So, you're thinking that there should be no problem at all if I pass the AccessToken from a device to a server, and the server impersonates the device with that AccessToken to post to the user's wall?

Comment: The server doesn’t need to impersonate anything - access tokens are not tied to a specific device, but only to the app id. Passing the token from the client to the server, to then make API requests using that token on/from the server, is perfectly valid.